# Good Apache security references?

Tags: security, apache, reference, single-sign-on

I've got an issue with Apache and Single Sign-on, which I cannot work out without good references as I am not a pro in Apache configuration. I tried to search in Amazon.com and found the matched book: [Apache security](http://www.apachesecurity.net/) has only three pages for this topic so I don't think it as a good reference in this case.

I am going to set up Apache test environment right now and will load the necessary modules, but I wonder if there is any good materials that I could follow? Of course I would search and Read The Fine Manuals from Apache website.

Many thanks to the suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i like this one "Preventing Web Attacks with Apache" Author: Ryan C Barnett
[http://www.amazon.com/Preventing-Attacks-Apache-Ryan-Barnett/dp/0321321286](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321286)
and this small article http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm